# Set style on TableRow in Android

Tags: java, android, android-styles

Using the Android SDK, there doesn't seem to be any way to set the style on a table row.  I want to do the equivalent of:

```
<TableRow
    style='@style/TableRow_classic' >
```

in code.  I would like something like:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setStyle(R.style.TableRow_classic);
```

Does anyone know how to find this?

Answer (score 13):

The best solution I've found to accomplish this is to create a "partial" layout representing the table row, with a style defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/tr_withborder" />
```

Then inflate it in your code, to use dynamically:

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.partial_table_row, null);
```

While not ideal, it does work for me

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there is no setStyle method. You could go through and set each individual property, but that defeats the purpose of separating your View from your controller  logic. Bad.

Has anyone figured out how to dynamically assign styles?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying myself to  set  style properties  obtained from my Theme  in  code.

My reason is that I want to use a style from my own Theme,  BUT  my User Interface Layout is entirely generated in code( using a custom layout builder), without defining any widgets in XML.  So I cannot  set a style in the XML layout of my widget – there isn’t any XML layout.

I  am thinking that I will be able to set this style in the code  of my widget  by using

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

Here it seems (to me) that

1. `AttributeSet set = null;` because this is what the XML inflater would have provided.
2. `int[] attrs  = R.styleable.MyWidget;`  defines what attributes I want to look at.
3. `int defStyleAttr = myWidgetStyle;` which is a reference, defined in my Theme, to a style for MyWidget.   These are both defined in XML files in res/values.
   “myWidgetStyle” follows the pattern of name the android developers have used in their code.
4. `defStyleRes = 0;`  I am hoping that I don’t need to think about this.

Then  to  get any property , such as a background  color,

```
Color  color = a.getColor(R.styleable.MyWidget_background,  R.color.my_default);

a.recycle();
```

This does seem to work –so far anyway.

It seems that  the android build system conveniently  generates the correct index to use in a.getColor, and names it `R.styleable.MyWidget_background` .  I didn’t  make this name, so  Android must have done it using my  XML for my styleable  MyWidget.

I expect one can look up the correct index by searching  the TypedArray for the required attribute , but that would be inefficient and the TypedArray looks like an unpleasant contraption to deal with. I would  use a very long stick to poke it!

Don