# android change style dynamically

Tags: android, coding-style

I've describef properties of my objects (nevermind what the object is) in styles.xml. I would like to change these properties dynamically in styles.xml.

Does anybody know how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am seeing contradicting answers to this question. This says [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144851/set-style-on-tablerow-in-android), but this says [no](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg22161.html). I looked at the android docs for the View and can not find any setStyle method.

Comment: Agreed, there is no `setStyle()` method. I know of no way to change your style at runtime. You can change most of the properties set by a style at runtime, but you have to do that property-by-property.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that like:

In Activity:

```
this.setTheme(R.style.ThemeRed);
```

In styles.xml:

```
<resources>
  <style name="ThemeBlack" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <<item name="android:background">#999999</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ThemeRed" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:background">#c81111</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it change described properties for all subViews of _current_ _ACTIVITY_ (but I need only for specific Views);

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to change these
>   properties dinamically in styles.xml.

What exactly do you want to change? The style applied at runtime?

I  am thinking you can do this in your code by using

```
TypedArray a =  context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

Here it seems (to me) that

1. `AttributeSet set = null;` because this is what the XML inflater would have provided.
2. `int[] attrs  = R.styleable.MyWidget;`  defines what attributes I want to look at.
3. `int defStyleAttr = myWidgetStyle;` which is a reference, defined in my Theme, to a style for MyWidget. These are both defined in XML files in res/values.
   “myWidgetStyle” follows the pattern of name the android developers have used in their code.
4. `defStyleRes = 0;` I am hoping that I don’t need to think about this.

Then  to  get any property , such as a background  color,

```
Color  color = a.getColor(R.styleable.MyWidget_background,  R.color.my_default);
a.recycle();
```

This does seem to work –so far anyway.

It seems that  the android build system conveniently  generates the correct index to use in a.getColor, and names it R.styleable.MyWidget_background.  I didn't  make this name, so  Android must have done it using my  XML for my styleable  MyWidget.

I expect one can look up the correct index by searching  the TypedArray for the required attribute , but that would be inefficient and the TypedArray looks like an unpleasant contraption to deal with. I would  use a very long stick to poke it!

Don