# How can i create a style programatically in android?

Tags: android, colors, styles, sharedpreferences, android-styles

I have an existing style defined in my android application. This is based out of colors defined in my colors.xml. I have a usecase to set the theme color programatically which i could using SharedPreferences but how can i use that color to define styles programatically ?

Comment: getResources().getColor(R.color.my_coolr); ?

Comment: styles deal with the state of the action as well. How about those ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084439/android-change-style-dynamically